# Hash-Map Translator Printing Null

Tags: java, input, null, hashmap, morse-code

In my Intro to OOP class, I have to make a morse code translator. It requires to read in a text file in and use that to match a user input for a morse code translation. My issue lies in that once I input the user input, it returns a null value instead of, well a morse code translation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  //File file = new File(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\myNAme\\Desktop\\morse.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\morse.txt"));
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    HashMap<String, String> morse = new HashMap<String, String>();

    while (scan.hasNextLine())
        {
         String[] columns = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
         morse.put(columns[0],(columns[1]));
        }           
    System.out.println(morse);
    System.out.println("What do you want to translate into morse code?: ");
    String eng2morse = input.nextLine();
    eng2morse = eng2morse.toUpperCase();
    System.out.print(morse.get(eng2morse));


    }
```

}

I've struggled with this project for a bit, I'm just looking to see what I did wrong and how I can fix it.

Text File (morse.txt)

A .-

B -...

C -.-.

D -..

E .

F ..-.

G --.

H ....

I ..

J .---

K -.-

L .-..

M --

N -.

O ---

P .--.

Q --.-

R .-.

S ...

T -

U ..-

V ...-

W .--

X -..-

Y -.--

Z --..

1 .----

2 ..---

3 ...--

4 ....-

5 .....

6 -....

7 --...

8 ---..

9 ----.

0 -----

/ -..-.

+ .-.-.

= -...-

. .-.-.-

, --..--

? ..--..

( -.--.

) -.--.-

- -....-

" .-..-.

_ ..--.-

' .----.

: ---...

; -.-.-.

$ ...-..-

Comment: Return null = key not found... could you display console logs please?

Comment: My guess is that the file content fills the map with entries like `A=.-, B=-...` and so on, so the map keys are all 1-character strings. Why would you then expect e.g. `get("AB")` to find a map entry? If you want to translate `AB` into `.- -...`, then ***you*** need to iterate over the characters of `eng2morse` and look up the individual morse symbols.

Comment: The text file can't be accessed anymore - AccessDenied. Can you share your data?

Comment: Apologies didn't realize, edited the post to include it in text.

Comment: Here's the console log: 

{"=.-..-., $=...-..-, '=.----., (=-.--., )=-.--.-, +=.-.-., ,=--..--, -=-....-, .=.-.-.-, /=-..-., 0=-----, 1=.----, 2=..---, 3=...--, 4=....-, 5=....., 6=-...., 7=--..., 8=---.., 9=----., :=---..., ;=-.-.-., ==-...-, ?=..--.., A=.-, B=-..., C=-.-., D=-.., E=., F=..-., G=--., H=...., I=.., J=.---, K=-.-, L=.-.., M=--, N=-., O=---, P=.--., Q=--.-, R=.-., S=..., T=-, U=..-, V=...-, W=.--, X=-..-, Y=-.--, Z=--.., _=..--.-}What do you want to translate into morse code?: 
hi
null

Answer (score 0):

There can be below reasons:

1. Trim the input you are taking from user.
2. while putting columns[0] trim it and also use toUpperCase() method as you are using it for User input.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
         morse.put(columns[0],columns[1]);
```

to

```
         morse.put(columns[1].trim(),columns[0].trim());
```